# jcenter and mavenCentral no longer support android dependencies?

Tags: android, maven, gradle, maven-central, jcenter

I'm building an Android project with gradle, according to the readme of this project https://github.com/sky-map-team/stardroid , but gradle failed to download dependencies from repository:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-annotations/23.1.0/support-annotations-23.1.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-annotations/23.1.0/support-annotations-23.1.0.jar
     Required by:
         stardroid:app:unspecified
...
```

It seems no such file (com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0) on jcenter, see https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/ .

This dependency cannot also be found on mavenCentral, see http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|support-annotations

How can I set repository for gradle to download such dependency ?

**RESOLVED**

Build success after download *Android Support Repository* and *Google Repository* in *Android SDK Manager*.

Comment: These come from your hard drive, in the form of the "Android Repository" that you install from your SDK Manager.

Comment: *Android Support Repository* or *Google Repository* in *Extra* ? I really have not installed them yet.

Comment: For that dependency, you want the "Android Repository". The "Google Repository" is for Google Play Services.

Comment: And I also have these: *compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'*, *compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'*

Comment: Those are from the "Google Repository".